# I did not get the difference between https.get() vs https.request() methods of nodejs npm package https

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, npm, https

```
    // # Nodejs Program 1
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.google.com/', (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });

}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});
// # Nodejs Program 2
const options = {
    hostname: 'www.google.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET'
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);

    res.on('data', (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});
req.end();
```

Both program 1 and program 2 giving me the same output. I want to know the difference between https.get() and https.request() of https package.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback convenience

Comment: "request" will give you more flexibility, e.g. if you want to do a POST request, or customise the headers a bit more. "get" is just a shortcut method which fills in some of those details for you in advance - primarily, always setting the HTTP method to "GET". The documentation already makes this pretty clear, IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"https.get" is only for GET requests - which are a special type of HTTP request that should be used only for retrieving data.

in "https.request" you can specify any HTTP method you want in the 'method' property - you could use "POST" (creating), PATCH (updating) or also GET.

More information here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Comment: "a special type of HTTP request used only for retrieving data."...actually, nothing technically prevents you from submitting data via a GET, if the server allows it. It's only a convention that GET is for fetching. A sensible convention, of course, but that's all it is.

Comment: Very true :) for the OP though, I would suggest not ever breaking convention even if you could technically do it

Answer (score 9):

See [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_url_options_callback):

> Like http.get() but for HTTPS.

and [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) says:

> Since most requests are GET requests without bodies, Node.js provides this convenience method. The only difference between this method and http.request() is that it sets the method to GET and calls req.end() automatically.